# Convert Business Account in to person Account (Associated with Portal User)

Tags: apex, community, person-accounts, data-migration

I am new to person Accounts in salesforce. I am trying to convert a Business Account, which is associated with the community user into person Account.

I saw the limitation in salesforce documentation saying that  **"You can't convert a business account to a person account if it was ever portal enabled."**

Can anyone please let me know how to do the data migration process.(Migration script Apex)

- Change the Business Account to Person Account
- Associate All the records to the newly created person Account

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the Account RecordTypeId field to the Person Account RecordTypeId. Be aware you are only allowed to specify the RecordTypeId field when converting the account, and only one Contact must be associated the Account when converting.

Be Aware:

> Manipulate the data such that the following conditions are met:
>   a. For each intended Person Account, one (and only one) Contact record
>   exists under the Account record.
>
> b. The Account and Contact have the same record owner.
>
> c. The Account and Contact have the same currency values (if
>   applicable).
>
> d. The Parent Account field on the Account and the Reports To field of
>   the Contact are both blank.
>
> e. The Account is not set as the Parent Account of any other Account
>   records.
>
> f. The Contact is not set as the Reports To of any other Contact
>   records.
>
> g. The Account and Contact have not been enabled as Partner/Customer
>   for Portal/Community.
>
> Using the data migration tool of your choice (i.e. something like the
>   Data Loader), change the record type of the target Account to the
>   desired Person Account record type. The detailed steps are listed
>   here. *Please note that this cannot be done with Workbench, as it will
>   return the error: "Cannot Specify Any Additional Fields When Marrying
>   Or Separating A Person-Account INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE"